# Debugging JUnit Internals

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit, eclipse-plugin

I'm wanting to dive into the internals of JUnit so that I can work towards creating a [custom runner](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5292).  I've attached the source to the JUnit within eclipse, but it seems that it's a slightly different build.  How do I go about "adding" a plugin for JUnit within eclipse which will sync up with the version of attached source that I have?  Is it as simple as creating a folder in the plugins directory, dropping in the jar file and restarting eclipse, then modifying the target runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create and debug a custom runner, you don't need to modify JUnit, the Eclipse JUnit plugin or mess about with the Eclipse installation. You only need to add make sure the new runner is on the classpath, i.e. on the build path.

Usually, to create a custom runner you extend [ParentRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.html), or more usually [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html). Using the following as an example, extending `ParentRunner#runChild` (the method which actually executes the test):

```
public class MyBlockJUnit4ClassRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
  public MyBlockJUnit4ClassRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
  }

  @Override
  protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
    System.out.println("before");
    super.runChild(method, notifier);
    System.out.println("after");
  }
}
```

Then the test:

```
@RunWith(MyBlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyRunnerTest {
  @Test public void testIt() {
    System.out.println("test it");
  }
}
```

This produces:

```
before
test it
after
```

For the [Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) classes, it's a little bit more complicated, but not very much.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I want to go down, but I was wanting to trod through the internals to see just which spots I need to hook into.  Looks like trolling through the docs will be my best bet.

Comment: @Scott, I would just clone the sources (https://github.com/KentBeck/junit) and import them into Eclipse. There is even an existing Eclipse project so you can just import existing project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Please consult this link http://alexsmail.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-install-eclipse-english.html

For the Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) download JUnit jars from here ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/eclipse/updates/3.7/R-3.7.1-201109091335/plugins/ (*junit*, source files and jdt).